# GCP Cloud Storage Transfer Service - Agents unable to connect to pool

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, podman, google-cloud-filestore

I wanted to make use of [GCP Cloud Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer) to sync data from on-premise. For this I had to install agents and connect them to a pool. I was following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/managing-on-prem-agents#install-agent), where they provide docker commands to install a transfer agent. Instead of docker, I used podman:

```
podman run -ti --name gcloud-config docker.io/google/cloud-sdk gcloud auth application-default login

podman run -d --rm \
--env https_proxy=<some_proxy> \
--volumes-from gcloud-config \
-v <some_dir>:<some_dir> \
gcr.io/cloud-ingest/tsop-agent:latest \
--project-id=<some_project_id> \
--hostname=$(hostname) \
--agent-pool=source_agent_pool
```

The agents do start but they aren't able to connect to the pool.
If I see the output of the agent container (using `podman attach containerID`)

```
0B/s txSum:      0B taskResps[copy:0 delete:0 list:0] ctrlMsgAge:10m50s (??) |
```

and agent.INFO logs:

```
Build target: //cloud/transfer/online/onprem/workers/agent:agent
Build id: <some_id>
I1222 06:47:51.288924       3 log_spam.go:51] Command line arguments:
I1222 06:47:51.288926       3 log_spam.go:53]  argv[0]: './agent'
I1222 06:47:51.288928       3 log_spam.go:53]  argv[1]: '--project-id=<project_id>'
I1222 06:47:51.288930       3 log_spam.go:53]  argv[2]: '--hostname=<hostname>'
I1222 06:47:51.288931       3 log_spam.go:53]  argv[3]: '--agent-pool=source_agent_pool'
I1222 06:47:51.288933       3 log_spam.go:53]  argv[4]: '--container-id=49be0b94bced'
I1222 06:47:51.289408       3 prodlayer.go:217] layer successfully set to NO_LAYER with source DEFAULT
I1222 06:47:53.148699       3 handler.go:45] TaskletHandler initialized to delete at most 1000 objects in parallel: 
I1222 06:47:53.148725       3 handler.go:48] TaskletHandler initialized with delete-files: 1024
I1222 06:47:53.148827       3 copy.go:145] TaskletHandler initialized with copy-files: &{0xc00073d2c0 10800000000000}
I1222 06:47:53.148860       3 handler.go:61] TaskletHandler initialized to process at most 256 list outputs in parallel: 
I1222 06:48:51.291680       3 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
I1222 06:49:51.291017       3 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
I1222 06:50:51.290721       3 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
I1222 06:51:51.291057       3 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
I1222 06:52:51.290677       3 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
I1222 06:53:51.290445       3 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
```

I also checked all the troubleshooting steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/troubleshooting-on-prem#not-connected), but couldn't find anything. Is it something to do with using podman instead of docker?